# save as dialog box in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I want to show the Save as dialog box when a user clicks an HTML button.
I am using DOJO and JavaScript.
In IE document.exec comes to rescue but in Firefox one needs to make changes in filesystem to use NSI.

Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the browser to download some data using a data url:

```
content = "This is the text for downloading";
window.location.href = "data:application/octet-stream,"+
          encodeURIComponent(content);
```

The main problem with this is that the user will not be able to choose a filename and the generated filename is some random hash. If you don't mind using Flash, you could use [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify), this will give you more control over the Save dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Have the HTML button href to a unknown document type. Say **FileName.xxxblah**.

This will automatically trigger the **Save as** Dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly what you're looking for, but the only **reliable** way I know of is to create a server side script on the server which will send the correct headers. In PHP this is how you'd do it:

```
header('Content-type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="mydocument.csv";' );
header('Content-length: '.(int)strlen($csvData));

print($csvData);
```

`Content-type` is the "mime type" of the document, and for compatibility with some browsers it's important this perfectly matches the extension of the filename.

`Content-Disposition: attachment` instructs the browser to download the page, even if it wouldn't normally do so for that mime-type, and you're able to provide the filename.

`Content-length` is the size of the download, this is optional but it must be provided if you want the user to see a progress bar for the download.

Some browsers will present a save as dialog, while others will simply save the file to the user's preferred download folder. You don't have much control over which will happen.